# What is the difference between 'a few', 'some', 'several', and 'multiple'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

'A few', 'some', 'several', 'multiple' seem to have, more or less, the same meaning. But, as I see it, 'a few' appears to be less than 'some' and 'several' while 'some' and 'several', in turn, appear to mean less than 'multiple'. Could you clarify the subject for me?

Comment: You have assumed correctly that 'few' and 'some' are used to descibe a small amount whilst 'several' means a larger amount. Multiple just means more than one and is the opposite of single.

Comment: _Some_ is an unspecified number, more than two (or an unspecified quantity of something uncountable). _A few_ is an unspecified _small_ number, but more than two. _Several_, I would say, is more than _a few_ but fewer than _many_! _Multiple_ can mean 'more than one' in some contexts, but usually means _many_.

Comment: @KateBunting No, "some" is not "more than two". Even one is some. q.v. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/some